# How can I start application in background, i.e. without showing GUI?

Tags: qt4

I'm using Qt for taking screenshots (screen printing).

```
QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
```

I'd like the application to start in background, i.e. I want it to be hidden when it starts (or even run in console mode).
How can I do that in Qt?

Comment: What do you mean, "without using GUI"?  Do you not want to include the GUI library?  Do you not want a window to show?  Do you want to hide the application into the task tray?

Comment: dont what the window to show , now i have this window show up each time i run the application . i dont want it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand, you need an app that, when executed, doesn't show a widget (UI) and runs in the background.

One way to achieve this is to launch the app and show an icon in System tray instead of showing a dialog/window on the screen.

You can code this something like this:

```
// main.cpp

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // this is the important bit
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
    
    // Say "Window" is your class which inherits QWidget or QDialog or QMainWindow
    Window window;
    // Don't call window.show()
    // Setup and invoke system tray icon in the constructor

    return app.exec();
}
```

There are a few other things you'd need to set. You can refer to the [System Tray Icon Example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-desktop-systray-example.html) for that.

---

**Update 2022:**
If you are looking for a way to invoke the app using a global shortcut you might wanna look into options other than [Qxt](https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/wiki/Home), as libqxt is no longer maintained and might not work with newer versions of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with Qt Console Application.

Remember to include `<GtGui>` in your headers.

Open your .PRO file, remove the line with `-= gui`

Comment: my pro file looks like this  
CONFIG   +=qt  console  
QT += core network

Comment: then you can add 'QT += gui'

Otherwise if you don't want to see the windows, you can 'hide()' it

Comment: mybe because i have : public QWidget inherent in my application
but i have to inherent from somewhere to use the Qt funtions
does making the window hide() is the right way .. its doesnt looks like ...its just my feeling

Comment: OK, so you have a QWidget in your application, and you don't want it to appear... maybe you can think of your requirements again?

Comment: @user63898, What kind of functions do you need?  Inheriting `QWidget` gives you a `QWidget`; you can get the power of signals and slots without inheriting `QWidget`.  (You can instead inherit `QObject`, for example.)

Comment: as i asked in my question , i need the functionality of printing screen and after playing with the code it seams i have to have QWidget and this QWidget trigger the GUI window to appear

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use QCoreApplication instead of QApplication:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
// ...
return app.exec();
}
```

By the way, you can select Console App in QtCreator, but I always use Empty Project.